# Start-stop azure app services using rest api

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-app-api

Is there any rest api to start-stop **AzureAppServices** programmatically ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find REST API documentation for Azure WebApps here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps.

Start WebApp: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps#WebApps_Start

Stop WebApp: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps#WebApps_Stop

Comment: Thanks for reply...what is the part before (/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/start?api-version=2016-08-01) ? Is it https://management.azure.com/ ?

Comment: That's correct. Assuming you're connecting to your Azure Subscription not hosted in China, Germany or US Gov regions, you would use management.azure.com.

Comment: I am getting bad request ...in response

Comment: Would you mind posting that as a separate question? Please include your code and the detailed error message you're getting.

Comment: You should unaccept my answer as now the question is considerably changed. This is why I asked you to post as another question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41716480/400-badrequest-while-call-rest-api-of-azure-web-app Now can you answer this question ?

Comment: Thanks! If I won't/can't, someone else will :)