# 400-BadRequest while call rest api of azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-envrmnt

```
 var client = new HttpClient();
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-version", "2016-05-31");
 var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new KeyValuePair<string, string>[]
 {
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("api-version", "2016-08-01")
 });
 content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml");
 var response = client.PostAsync("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/SuscriptionID/resourceGroups/Default-Web-SoutheastAsia/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/MyAppName/stop?", content);
```

This is how I make a call to Azure WebApp rest api but I am getting statuscode : BadRequest

Comment: You should read the response also, it'll tell you more.

Comment: And your content type most certainly is not application/xml, it is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Maybe you wanted to set the Accept header instead?

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your code:

- You're mixing `Azure Service Management API` with `Azure Resource Manager (ARM) API`. API to stop a web app is a Resource Manager API thus you don't need to provide `x-ms-version`.
- You're missing the `Authorization` header in your request. ARM API requests require an authorization header. Please see this link on how to perform ARM API requests: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/gettingstarted/.

Based on these, I modified your code:

```
    static async void StopWebApp()
    {
        var subscriptionId = "<your subscription id>";
        var resourceGroupName = "<your resource group name>";
        var webAppName = "<your web app name>";
        var token = "<bearer token>";
        var url = string.Format("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{2}/stop?api-version=2016-08-01", subscriptionId, resourceGroupName, webAppName);
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        var t = await client.PostAsync(url, null);
        var response = t.StatusCode;
        Console.WriteLine(t.StatusCode);
    }
```

Please try using this code. Assuming you have acquired proper token, the code should work.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.I am having issure regarding token.Can you look into this question please.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41736162/unauthorized-when-try-to-get-token-using-arm-api

Comment: I am getting error :: {"error":{"code":"AuthorizationFailed","message":"The client 'someId' with object id 'someId' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Web/sites/stop/action' over scope '/subscriptions/Subscriptionid/resourceGroups/Default-Web-SoutheastAsia/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/Webapp'."}}

Comment: You're experiencing `Role-based access control`. Basically you're getting this error is because the user (in your case application or `Service Principal` in Azure terms) doesn't have permissions to perform this operation. Please see this link on how you can assign permissions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-configure. For simplicity, I would recommend you assign the user in question a `Contributor` role.