# Unauthorized when try to get token using ARM API

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to get token from using **Azure Resource Manager** API but getting **401-Unauthorized** in response.I have my code as below :

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
   "Basic",
   Convert.ToBase64String(
       System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
           string.Format("{0}:{1}", client_Id, client_secret))));

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new KeyValuePair<string, string>[]{

            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials")
        });

content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

var response = client.PostAsync("https://login.windows.net/subscriptionId/oauth2/token", content);
```

Comment: Have you seen the link I posted in the answer to your other question? I suggest you check that first on how to get authorisation token. What you're doing is absolutely incorrect.

Comment: Yeah,I did and I am using ,Client credentials grant.@GauravMantri

Comment: Please show the code you're using to get the token.

Comment: I have already given the code in the question

Comment: From where did you take this code? From what I know, there's no `subscriptionId` parameter when getting auth token.

Comment: then what is the api to get the token ?.Actually given links are not opened  in that document..

Comment: Have you solved this issue, any updates?

Comment: Your question does not give enough information to help. Anyway, do you have MFA enabled on the account you are using? That might be the reason why it is not working. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, you could refer to the following code to retrieve your token:

```
var client = new HttpClient();

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new KeyValuePair<string, string>[]{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("resource", "https://management.core.windows.net/"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "{ClientID}"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", "{ClientSecret}")
});

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
var response = await client.PostAsync("https://login.windows.net/{TennantID}/oauth2/token", content);

Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

Result:

[image]

For more details, you could refer to this [blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_stranger/2016/10/21/using-the-azure-arm-rest-apin-get-access-token/) about using the Azure ARM REST API – Get Access Token.

Answer (score 0):

I dont fully understand your code but i know how to construct ARM API calls so i can help you out with the core facts.
What jumps out at me is the fact that your POST URL looks wrong:

1. you should be using https://login.microsoftonline.com/ - check out the following blogpost [Simplifying our Azure AD Authentication Flows](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2015/03/06/simplifying-our-azure-ad-authentication-flows/)
2. There needs to be the tenantID in your POST uri, not the subscriptionID. Access to subscriptions is managed through assigning RBAC Roles to the serivceprincipal created for the AzureAD App

Here is an example call. I use Postman to check if my constructed calls use the correct values and parameters:

Request

```
POST /[YOURTENANTID]/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0 HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Expect: 100-continue
Postman-Token: [token]

grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=[YOURCLIENTID]&client_secret=[YOUR-URLENCODED-Secret]&resource=https://management.azure.com/
```

response:

```
{
 "token_type": "Bearer",
 "expires_in": "3599",
 "ext_expires_in": "0",
 "expires_on": "1485695000",
 "not_before": "1485691100",
 "resource": "https://management.azure.com/",
 "access_token": "[TOKEN]"
}
```